# add urls in reference

Tags: urls

i want to add urls in my reference

i am using the following code in my .tex file

```
    \bibitem{bl}Business Logic layer, \url{http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_logic_layer}, 23 12 2011.
```

however, i get the following output in my console

```
    ! Undefined control sequence.
    l.477 \bibitem{bl}Business Logic layer, \url
                                        {http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bu...

    ? 
    ! Missing $ inserted.
    <inserted text> 
            $
    l.477 ...rl{http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_
                                              logic_layer}, 23 12 2011.
    ? 
    ! Extra }, or forgotten $.
    l.477 ....wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_logic_layer}
                                              , 23 12 2011.
    ? 

    ! LaTeX Error: Command \item invalid in math mode.
```

whereas my .pdf file entry against this code is this.

```
    Business Logic layer,
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Businesslogiclayer; 23122011

what is this error about and how can i set this right?

Comment: Have you loaded the `url` package?

Comment: Loading the `hyperref` should also work, i.e., make the command `\url` available.

Comment: @Mico that's because `hyperref` loads `url`…

Comment: i m a newbee with latex so trying to learn its tricks, many a times the "how to do this" is not that descriptive. thanx

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To use the command `\url` you need to load the `url` package by adding `\usepackage{url}` to your preamble.

Many packages (like `hyperref`) load `url` automatically.

Comment: thanx a bunch :)

Comment: Thanks. From my experience, to include a url in the `bibitem` block, `hyperref` didn't work whereas the `url` package did. I have no idea why.